# PHP foreach json_encode issues

Tags: php, mysql, json

I got problems with `json_encode`.

My code below:

```
$jsonfiles = array('http://example.com/myjsonishere.php'); //Here's my JSON
foreach ( $jsonfiles as $jsonfile ) {

    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($jsonfile);
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $json = json_decode(stripslashes($data));

    foreach ((array)$json as $u => $z){

        foreach ($z as $n => $line){
            //get the tweet details
            $grap_item1 = $line['grap1'];
            $grap_item2 = $line['grap2'];
            $grap_item3 = $line['grap3'];

            // execute this insertion
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Without that `stripslashes`, `json_last_error` would show error number 4 but now it's 0, so I'm good to go.
Without `(array)` in first `foreach` PHP error pop up:

> Invalid foreach argument

Even if I have tested after `$json = json_decode(stripslashes($data));` line : `if(is_array($json))` the test is `TRUE` but still the foreach will not work without `(array)`

Anyway, in theory, my code passes the first foreach, but if I put inside first foreach loop e.g. `var_dumb($z)` or whatever, it will not print anything. So I guess my code is stuck in the first foreach.

Please, let me know if I could provide more information.

Comment: I dont think `file_get_content` is for json data. What exactly `http://example.com/myjsonishere.php` returns?

Comment: it return 51 different rows which I suppose to insert to the database. If I use e.g. 'var_dump' BEFORE json_decode it will print the json file from the URL but after json_encode, not a chance. It will print Array(0) or NULL or pretty much anything else than the correct JSON. But with that stripslashes I can get at least json_last_error to show 0. So I would be good to go I think.

Comment: have you tried it without `file_get_contents`? Just `$data = json_decode($jsonfile, true);`?

Comment: @Autor69 Still nothing. var_dump($json) print out NULL and print_r print out blank

Comment: @Autor69 and after first foreach still nothing

Comment: An if you do var_dump right after `$jsonfiles = ('http://example.com/myjsonishere.php');` what does it print? Is it array or string

Comment: Well, If I do var_dump($jsonfiles) it will of course print that URL inside the array but if I use `file_get_contents($jsonfile)` inside VERY first foreach, and do var_dump after that, it will print all the json rows.

Comment: @Autor69 and it's array

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> string(46) "http://example.com/myjsonishere.php" }`

Comment: You do not need to make it array. Ommit the `array` after `$jsonfiles =`. Then you do not need first foreach. Just `$jsondata = file_get_contents(URL)`;

Comment: @Autor69 I did this : delete first `foreach` -> URL inside `$jsonfiles` (no array) -> `$jsondata = file_get_contents($jsonfiles)` -> `$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);` -> `$json = json_decode(stripslashes($data));` and right after those lines `var_dump` print `NULL`

Or should I use ONLY `$jsondata = file_get_contents(URL)` without json_decode?

Comment: `json_decode` is okay but why twice? You can do `$data = json_decode(stripslashes($jsondata),true)`

Comment: Yes, actually I used before `$data = json_decode(stripslashes($jsondata), true);` But either way, after that line var_dump is NULL

Comment: You must have typo in your json, missing bracket or column

Comment: Can you send a sample of it?

Comment: @Autor69 Well, is there some way how I could easiest send it for you? Anyway, there is small sample how it start `stdClass Object ( [orders] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => id_here [order_number] => number_here [created_at] => TIME_HERE [updated_at] => TIME_HERE [completed_at] => TIME_HERE [status] => processing [currency] => CURRENCY_HERE [total] => price_here` There is lot of rows.

Comment: this is data that are returned from `var_dump(file_get_contents($jsonfiles))`, right?

Comment: yes and `string(66577)` is in very start of the returned value.

Comment: `http://example.com/myjsonishere.php` does not return json. In that script type on the end `return json_encode($yourObject); Then in the second script `json_decode(file_get_contents(URL))`

Comment: @Autor69 I'm sorry, you lost me. Could you please provide bit more detailed information.  Do you mean `the end` right after those two foreach ? and `second script` do you mean the second foreach ?

Comment: No, I mean on the end of script: `http://example.com/myjsonishere.php` . This script should return json data, nit php object

Comment: @Autor69 Ok now I got it. Before end of the second script, there was `print_r($object)` I changed it `return json_encode($object)` and then in the first script I put `$json = json_encode(file_get_contents($jsonfiles));
var_dump($json);` Now it print `string(2) """"` . I guess I'm missing something

Comment: @Autor69 `$json = json_encode(file_get_contents($jsonfiles));` I changed `json_decode` now var_dump print NULL

Comment: and `var_dump(file_get_contents(URL))` returns the string of `json`?

Comment: @Autor69 it returns `string(0) ""` Btw, after I changed that `print_r($object)` to `return json_encode($object)` the `example.com/myjsonishere.php` is blank

Comment: instead of `return` try `echo`. Like `echo(json_encode($object));`

Comment: @Autor69 Awesome, now the `myjsonishere.php` looks correct. It's json data. But now in the second script I have `$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonfiles));
var_dump($json);` This returns something like this `object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["orders"]=> array(10) ` .............. I guess that's not correct, right ?

Comment: that depends what you want to do with it. You can have foreach on object or array. If you prefer array change it to `$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonfiles), true);`

Comment: @Autor69 cool, thanks!! Finally it works! You can't even image how much you just helped me. Thank you!